# How can I see the overlay of two features (point & polygon)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to open two digitized layers, one containing points in a region and second which I have downloaded separately for the region as polygon layer. I would like to overlay two of these layers to see which point belongs to which area. 
The problem is, I can not see an overlay of layers (points on polygon).

Comment: What CRS do these layers have? What extent is reported under properties, metadata tab? Have you enabled `On-the-fly-reprojection`? What is your project CRS?

Comment: When I am opening the points layer, the CRS selector window opens, which WGS 84, EPSG 4326 is defined. For the polygon which I downloaded from http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata, the same CRS is defined as well. 
******Extents for Points layer:
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 188184.13,101268.38 : xMax,yMax 2332803.90,779600.64
Layer Spatial Ref System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
******
and for the polydon,
Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 99.6407,0.855001 : xMax,yMax 119.27,7.38056
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

Comment: The point layer can not be in EPSG:4326. The extent is far beyond +/- 180/90°E/N. The coordinates seem to be in metres or feet. You have to find out which CRS belongs to those coordinates, and assign that to the layer.

Comment: The point layer might be in GDM2000/Peninsula RSO, EPSG:3375.